# unable to deploy a yeoman angular.js app to heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku

I am following this tutorial:

http://davemax.com/heroku-deploy-yeoman-angular-app/

Steps:

1) $ grunt build --force
2) $ grunt serve dist

app seems to build fine

I then created a procfile with the following content:

```
web: node server/app.js
```

then copied and pasted package.json from route directory to dist, adding the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/app.js",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "update-webdriver": "node node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
```

then to check the app locally I do this:

$ foreman start web

I am faced with the error:

```
20:15:08 web.1  | started with pid 57020
20:15:08 web.1  | module.js:338
20:15:08 web.1  |     throw err;
20:15:08 web.1  |           ^
20:15:08 web.1  | Error: Cannot find module '/Users/xxx/Desktop/webapp/dist/server/app.js'
20:15:08 web.1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
20:15:08 web.1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
20:15:08 web.1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
20:15:08 web.1  |     at startup (node.js:129:16)
20:15:08 web.1  |     at node.js:814:3
20:15:08 web.1  | exited with code 1
20:15:08 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

My folder looks like this:

[image]

It seems as though there are files missing. I have removed /dist from .gitignore.